# Command Button not calling action function

Tags: apex, visualforce, commandbutton

I am trying to call action function from command button  but for some reason the method in the action function is not getting invoked at all. Can any one please point out what is the issue here.

```
<apex:commandButton id="songdbabc" onclick="Synchfromsongdb('{!wrapSong.seqObject.id}','Synch');" value="Synch from song db" />

<apex:actionFunction id="Synchfromsongdb" immediate="true" status="counterStatus" action="{!Synchsongmethod}" name="Synchfromsongdb">
```

Controller code

```
public PageReference Synchsongmethod()
{
        system.debug('synch song method is called');
        List<Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c> recordToVerify=new List<Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c>();
          Id seqIdsynch =Id.ValueOf(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('seqIdsynch'));
       system.debug('seqIdsynch'+sid);
        Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c newRecord =[Select id,Flagged_for_Delete__c,RapidCue_Delete_Timestamp__c, Verified__c from Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c where id=:seqIdsynch and Sequence_Order_No__c!=0];
       system.debug('newRecord '+newRecord );

               newRecord.Flagged_for_Delete__c=true;
        newRecord.RapidCue_Delete_Timestamp__c = system.now();
                recordToVerify.add(newrecord);

        update recordToVerify;
        return null;
 }
```

Comment: why the actionFunction is needed here? You can directly call controller method and pass parameters

Comment: I tried that too still i was getting list has no rows error <apex:commandButton id="songdbabc" action="{!synchsongmethod}" value="Synch from song db">
             <apex:param name="seqId" value="{!wrapSong.seqObject.id}" assignTo="{!sid}"/>
</apex:commandbutton>  
controller method
public id sid{get;set;}public PageReference Synchsongmethod(){List<Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c> recordToVerify=new List<Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c>();
                  Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c newRecord =[Select id,Flagged_for_Delete__c,RapidCue_Delete_Timestamp__c, Verified__c from Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c where id=:sid ];

Comment: The id returned is null , Can you please suggest what can be the problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing, actionFunction is not needed here.

Secondly, be sure to use `reRender` attribute of the `apex:commandButton`.

```
<apex:commandButton id="songdbabc" value="Synch from song db" action="{!Synchsongmethod}" reRender="form">
    <apex:param name="seqIdsynch" value="{!wrapSong.seqObject.id}" assignTo="{!seqIdsynch}"/>
</apex:commandButton>
```

Thirdly, using `assignTo` attribute directly assigns the value to controller class' attribute

Fourthly, no need to type cast the String to Id when using in SOQL

**Controller**

```
public String seqIdsynch {get;set;}
public PageReference gotoContactDetailPage()
{
    System.debug('seqIdsynch=' + seqIdsynch);

    Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c newRecord =[Select id,Flagged_for_Delete__c,RapidCue_Delete_Timestamp__c, Verified__c from Cue_Sheet_Sequence__c 
    where id=:seqIdsynch 
    and Sequence_Order_No__c!=0];

    system.debug('newRecord '+newRecord );
    ...
    return null;
}
```